# How to print in black and white or grey scale in ubuntu 16.04 or above?

Tags: printing

Like windows greyscale option, I found no option in ubuntu 16.04 for printing in 'black and white' or 'grey scale' mode.
How can I use these modes?

Comment: It is possible by installing HPLIP from [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip).
But I want to do it using default printers.